# How to use custom classes in another file in Java?

Tags: java

I have one class in one file called `src/PostfixConverter`:

```
import java.io.*;



public class PostfixConverter {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ...
        LinkedListStack lls = new LinkedListStack();
        ...
}
```

and `LinkedListStack.java`

```
public class LinkedListStack {
    private Node head;  // the head node

    ...

    public LinkedListStack() { // internal data structure to keep track of head
        head = null;
    }

    ...
}
```

So I think they're both in the default package but `postfixConverter` cannot find the LinkedListStack class or symbol. I get the error: `error: cannot find symbol`. What can I do to resolve this without using packages? Shouldn't they both be in the default package

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You **can not import a class without package**.

It is clearly mentioned in official documentation

> It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

More can be read on [Oracle Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/packages.html)

Comment: It seems I can compile both at the same time with javac <both java classes> and then it runs.

Comment: I doubt, you will execute postfixConverter  and at run time it will try to find address(package) of **LinkedListStack**. When It doesn't found it throws exception. Both may available in classpath

Comment: But when I compile them both together using javac... it works. Why is this?

Comment: When you compiled through javac it must have generated both class with dot(.) known as default package. Now to JVM both are available in current working directory, so it worked.

Comment: You're saying inside the class files there are package declarations now? I'm using JDK 12.

Comment: Yes, which is **default(unnamed)** assigned by JVM

Comment: If I wanted to use explicit packages... how would I do this. can you write an answer example and I"ll give you credit?